# Parse JSON string within JSON and other fields

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a file in `s3` which when unzipped has something of this format

```
{"a": "foo",
 "b": "bar",
 "c": : "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"}
```

Now I know I can parse the value of `c` by doing `jq '.c | fromjson | .hello'`

But let's say I want all the values from this json, `a, b, and c`. This is the code snippet I currently have:

```
aws s3 cp s3://somebucket/somekey.gz - | gunzip | jq '[.a, .b]'
```

How do I incorporate grabbing the value from `c` into this expression?

Comment: Is your JSON valid? It needs to have a bracket present `"c": ["{\"hello\": \"world\"}"]`

Comment: `"c": : "` is *definitely* not valid JSON. Please test your example data to make sure it's genuinely representative of the input format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want all the values from this json, a, b, and c

**`jq`** solution for valid JSON structure:

```
... | jq '[.a, .b, (.c | fromjson | .[])]'
```

- `.[]` - returns all the values of the array/object

The output:

```
[
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "world"
]
```